# How to convert OSM polyline data to polygons?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, polygon, line

I just now downloaded OSM data .I am having the data as polylines. I want that polylines as polygons is it possible in Qgis?below I also posted the screen shot of the polyline also.[image]

Comment: You are able to download polygon data from OSM with the QGIS OSM plugin. Would this approach be good enough for you?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn no brother I even tried that it is giving me only the closed area polygons which is totally useless for me............

Comment: @Arun - what other sort of polygons were you expecting?

Comment: @iant see the above picture you can see the individual street lines know I want each and every lines as  a polygon .so that I can create a Centroid point . I also tried lines to polygon & polygoniser option It all lands me in miserable condition only.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that OSM stores ways as lines - wysiwyg :-)

Comment: @iant sorry i cant follow you?

Comment: roads are stored as lines - the only polygons in the OSM data are the closed ones that QGIS downloaded.

Comment: Are you trying to create polygons which represent the areas between roads?

Comment: yes@underdark !!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about what you want too. But if you want to obtain the 'centroid' for each feature in a polyline layer you could try applying a small buffer to it, which will make a polygon layer with a polygon for each polyline. You could then obtain your centroids from this.

[image]